# Is there a simple way to turn a coordinate system "inside out"?

Tags: geometry

I have the following function, depicted on this image:

[image]

The strange thing is, that I only know the coordinate system from the "inside out", that means I know the lengths `b`, `c`, `e` and `f`, but I don't know `a` and `d`. Neither do I know the function. My goal is to calculate `a` and `d`. I could assume the function is quadratic, (even if it's not, it would be sufficient as an approximation, if I swapped the two axes).

I also know the length `a+d`. It's as if the two axes were a thread being stretched over the edge of a cube, and I can move it, and I know all the markings on it, but not the position where it contacts the edge.

The problem is, if I try to use my assumptions on the function for my calculations, I end up with

```
g(a) = d
g(a+b) = d + e
g(a+b+c) = d + e + f
```

As I don't know `a` and `d`, this results in a big mess in my calculations, and I can't get anywhere, because I don't know the origin of my coordinate system.

As I know the "outside" part of my coordinate system better than the "inside" of it, is there any transformation I can use to make my job easier? (or a completely different strategy to solve my original problem?)

Comment: Would it help to put the origin at the point you currently call $(a,d)$?  The lower left corner becomes $(-a,-d)$ but is decoupled from the other lengths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know $b,c,e,f$ you have three points on a parabola so should be able to determine it.  As in my comment, let the origin be at your $(a,d)$.  Then your functional form is $x=py^2+qy$.  There is no constant term as it goes through the origin.  If we substitute in the known points we get $b=pe^2+qe, (b+c)=p(e+f)^2+q(e+f)$  This is two equations in two unkowns $(p$ and $q)$.

Comment: You are right, it does even become a simple interpolation problem even if I decide to use another form for my function (it is taken from real-life measurements, so it might not be one continuous function describing my "red line" from one end to the other). I arrived to this problem after a long time of simplifying a 3d problem, I don't know how could I miss such a simple solution!

Comment: by the way, shouldn't it be $b=pe^2+qe$ ?

Comment: vsc I think Ross is assuming you mean for f to be the distance from e, so he's added the values, to compute the distance between f and d. Just as he did for b + c (to compute the distance from a to c).

Comment: @vsc:  amWhy is correct.  Based on the original posting, it appears each segment is separate-that c does not include a or b, for example.

Comment: If the origin was moved to $(a,d)$ then $g(b) = e$, not $d$

Comment: @vsz:  you are right.  Fixed.  Thanks

Comment: Maybe I'm too tired and don't see what the problem is, but your solution gives a convex parabola instead of the rotated one. You write $x=py^2+qx$ but use it as $x=py^2+qy$

Comment: Actually, I should forget the parabola. As $a$ and $d$ are nearly identical (based on empiric data), it seems the function is nearly linear near the origin. I wonder what can it be...